# type of (car list) in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

If I define a list in scheme like this

```
(define list '(when i type I 1 23 4 2))
```

What's the type of the thing (car list) returns? And another question is: can I convert it to the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the list shown in the question, the car is the *symbol* `'when`. You can verify it, but first let's change the name of the list to something else, for avoiding a name collision with the built-in `list` procedure:

```
(define lst '(when i type I 1 23 4 2))
(symbol? (car lst))
> #t
```

The `#t` (`true`) in the last line shows that indeed the first element is a symbol. If you need to convert it to a string, simply do this:

```
(symbol->string (car lst))
> "when"
```

**EDIT :**

Answering the question in the comments, this should work:

```
(define (isvariable? symbol)
  (and (symbol? symbol)
       (eqv? (string-ref (symbol->string symbol) 0)
               #\?)))
```

Comment: Ok then what's the problem with this: `(define (isvariable? symbol)
 (equal? (string-ref (string->symbol  symbol) 0) #\?)) ` and this `(filter isvariable? '(?when dremd type 1 2 3 4 )) `

Comment: First, you have `string->symbol` when you intended `symbol->string`. Second, the list you're processing contains both symbols and numbers, so `symbol->string` will fail for the numbers. I edited my answer with an implementation that works.

Comment: @IonelMerca If this answer is correct and was helpful for you, please don't forget to click the check mark to its left, for accepting it.

Comment: @IonelMerca you're welcome! please don't forget to accept the answer :) (click the check mark to its left)